# Не могу написать sql запрос на языке ORM sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

Всем привет, есть запрос к БД

```
SELECT  distinct "game".genre::json->0->>'name', game.title, game."release" 
from game
where lower("game".genre::json->0->>'name') = 'action'and (game."release"  between '1990-01-01' and '2000-01-01') 
order by game."release"
```

Вот мои попытки написать его на бекенде:

```
query = select(distinct(cast(game_table.c.genre[0]['name'], JSON))).limit(10)
result = await db.execute(query)
```

Я не могу найти как в sqlalchemy обозначается -> и ->> символы, ::json вроде как через cast или тоже нет. В общем прошу помощи или ссылки на документацию в конкретный раздел где подобное есть.

Вот вариант где я указываю что хочу все поля где есть Action получить, но выдаёт почему то None везде

```
    query = select(game_table.c.genre[0]['name']).filter(cast(game_table.c.genre[0]['name'], Text) == 'Action').limit(10)
```

БД postgres 15

Comment: А у тебя колонка `genre` в SqlAchemy типизирована правильно? д.б. `Column('genre', JSON)`

Comment: `cast(game_table.c.genre[0]['name'], JSON)` - вообще бессмыслица. Ты к JSON кастуешь резальтат, вместо колонки `genre`.

Comment: `filter(cast(game_table.c.genre[0]['name'], Text) == 'Action')` - в SQL запросе `= 'action'`. Ты уж определись, с большой буквы или с маленькой д.б.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov а я использу. функцию lower в запросе, мне не важно с какой писать

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov да, поле жанр типизировано правильно